# Invalid BLOB ID on insert into Firebird 2.5

Tags: insert, blob, firebird2.5

I am trying to insert some binary data into a Firebird BLOB field using the API from a C++ application. My code is basically as follows (error handling omitted), after the official Firebird API manual:

```
extern db_conn_t global_db;
extern db_txn_t  global_txn;
extern db_stmt_t global_stmt;

#define mydb          (global_db.db_conn)
#define mytr          (global_txn.dt_txn)
#define mystmt        (global_stmt.ds_stmt)
#define status_vector (global_db.db_status)


isc_blob_handle hblob;
ISC_QUAD blobid;
XSQLDA *pinsqlda;
short flag[NUM_FIELDS];
memset (&flag[0], 0, NUM_FIELDS*sizeof(short));

hblob = NULL;
memset (&blobid, 0, sizeof(blobid));

isc_create_blob2(status_vector, &mydb, &mytr, &hblob, &blobid, 0, NULL);
isc_put_segment(status_vector, &hblob, payload_len, (char*)payload);
isc_close_blob(status_vector, &hblob);

pinsqlda = (XSQLDA *)calloc(1, XSQLDA_LENGTH(NUM_FIELDS));
...
pinsqlda->sqlvar[4].sqldata = (char *)&(blobid);
pinsqlda->sqlvar[4].sqltype = SQL_BLOB + 1;
pinsqlda->sqlvar[4].sqllen  = sizeof(blobid);
pinsqlda->sqlvar[4].sqlind  = &flag[4];
...
```

Then the query is submitted in the same way as many other instances elsewhere in the application, so I'm confident there is no problem there.
The blob creation completes with no error, but when the query is submitted, the returned error code is "invalid BLOB ID".
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

### Update (from comment)

I just re-ordered my statements to put the blob creation after the definition of the XSQLDA structure and calls to isc_dsql_allocate_statement and isc_dsql_prepare, and lo! it works without error. So my immediate problem is solved, but I'd still appreciate knowing what exactly was going wrong.

Comment: Um. OK, I just re-ordered my statements to put the blob creation _after_ the definition of the XSQLDA structure and calls to isc_dsql_allocate_statement and isc_dsql_prepare, and lo! it works without error. So my immediate problem is solved, but I'd still appreciate knowing what exactly was going wrong.

Comment: You don't actually show statement prepare / execute nor the transaction start. The error you post is usually caused by creating the blob in a different transaction than the one you use to execute the insert or update: as long as a blob id hasn't been linked to a table, it is not visible in other transactions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, you're absolutely right. I was trying to keep out extraneous detail from my code sample and hadn't picked up on the point that you make. Yes, looking back at the code again, the blob creation **was** in a different transaction from the statement preparation. In general, I have to say the level of accessible Firebird documentation is not good, because that was a point I hadn't found made in either the online or the printed (Borrie's Firebird book) documentation. Many thanks!

Comment: I posted my original comment as an answer now. The documentation is a lacking in this area. I think the original manual writers for Borland/Interbase assumed that the fact that you need to include a transaction with blob creation makes it clear that blob creation and statement execution need to use the same transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show statement prepare / execute nor the transaction start which is relevant for this problem: The error you post is usually caused by creating the blob in a different transaction than the one you use to execute the insert or update: as long as a blob id hasn't been linked to a table, it is not visible in other transactions.